# How to fail a maven build, when quality gate fails?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-plugin, sonarcloud

Earlier I use `sonar-maven-plugin version 3.2` then when a Sonar quality gate fails the build also used to fail. Now I am using `sonar-maven-plugin version 3.7.0.1746`, it does not happen so. Even if quality gate fails maven build succeeded. Now when I use version 3.2 in pom.xml it gives the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project maven-webapp: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server -> [Help 1]
```

While using `sonar-maven-plugin version 3.7.0.1746` doesn't give the above error.

This is how I add the plugin in Pom.xml

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

I also got to know that in version 3.2 there was some post-job action like `org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.QualityGateBreaker`.

How can it be done now?
I am using https://sonarcloud.io/ for sonar.

Comment: If you find a solution please let us know.

Comment: I'd guess it was a design change. At least it looks like they changed Jenkins integration features because fundamental changes in SonarQube that made it a bad pattern to use. See: https://blog.sonarsource.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/ Also, they (re)introduced a different implementation for Jenkins pipelines: https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/ Still, none of this exactly covers Maven, nor Sonar Cloud.

Answer (score 3):

If Sonar Qube Server version is bigger than 8.1, `sonar.qualitygate.wait=true` can be used:

```
mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

Otherwise, there is a maven plugin to detect Sonar Quality Gate Result:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>io.github.r0bb3n</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-quality-gate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
  </plugin>
```

Then, you will run the following Maven Command:

```
mvn sonar-quality-gate:check
```